# Show Products Special From Date - Optimize Magento Script

Tags: php, magento-1.6

I am trying to list all products that have a special from date that is within the last 72 hours. The script works fine except over 400 products it times out.

I think I am loading too many collections or not correctly utilizing the ones that are loaded so I really just need some optimization advice please.

Here is the script:

```
<?php


set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

try
{
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId(1);
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prodIds=$products->getAllIds();
    $product_count = 0;
    $products_changed = 0;

    //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    echo "Price Changes Last 72 Hours<br><br>";

    foreach($prodIds as $productId) 
    {
        $product_count++;
        //$products->load($productId);

        // load product data
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

        $special_price = round($product->getSpecialprice(),2);
        $human_readable_date = $product->getSpecialFromDate();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $specialPriceFromDate = strtotime($human_readable_date);
        $time_now = microtime(true);
        $product_link = "http://www.mydomain.com.au/".$product->getUrlPath(); 
        $date_array = explode( ' ', $human_readable_date);
        $short_date = $date_array[0];

        if (($time_now - $specialPriceFromDate) < 259200)
        {
            $products_changed++; 
            echo "SKU: " . '<a href=' . $product_link . '>' . $sku . '</a>' . "  Date Changed: " . $short_date . " New Price $" . $special_price . "<br>";
        }
        //if ($product_count == 400) exit;  
    }
}

catch(Exception $e){
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 1, 'me@mydomain.com.au', $headers);
    die($e->getMessage());
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first loading a complete collection and then are loading all the products again, one by one. This will result in a huge memory consumption and will be slow.

Additionally you're loading *all* product attributes (which can be hundreds), but mainly seem to be only interested in just a few of them.

To optimize both issues, I'd recommend to directly filter for only the products of interest:

```
$iNow = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$iFrom = $iNow - (60 * 60 * 24 * 3);
$oProductCollecion = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'special_price', 'url_path'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'special_from_date',
         array('from' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $iFrom))
    );

foreach($oProductCollecion as $oProduct) {
    $product_link = "http://www.mydomain.com.au/" . $oProduct->getUrlPath();
    $sku = $oProduct->getSku();
    $short_date = $oProduct->getSpecialFromDate();
    $special_price = round($oProduct->getSpecialPrice(), 2);
    echo "SKU: " . '<a href=' . $product_link . '>' . $sku . '</a>' . "  Date Changed: " . $short_date . " New Price $" . $special_price . "<br>";
}
```